# How to start VNC server on start-up in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, startup

I've been struggling with this long enough to ask yet another startup script question.

I've got a startup script that is relatively simple, ie:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          startVNC
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: Start VNC server at boot time
# Description:       Test
### END INIT INFO

#!/bin/sh
echo "JOB RUN AT $(date)"
echo "============================"
echo ""
/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 24
```

Obviously it's only the last line that's really important. The script is executable, ie.

```
ls -l startVNC
```

yields:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 406 2011-12-07 15:45 startVNC
```

When I execute it when logged in over ssh as `my_user` vncserver starts and I am able to see the GUI from my desktop. So then I tried 5 things to make it run on start-up:

1. Copying my script to `/etc/init.d/`, calling `update-rc.d -f startVNC defaults` (also with `99` after `defaults` to make sure everything `vncserver` depended on is already running). I checked all the generated symbolic links were there in the `/etc/rcX.d/` folders. But it didn't work on reboot or start-up
2. Adding my script to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`
3. Adding to `crontab -e` as `@reboot /home/my_user/scripts/startVNC`
4. Adding my script to `/etc/init.d/rcS`
5. Adding my script to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications in Gnome

but none of them worked. What more can I check. Is there an error in my script maybe? I guess the process'es owner has to be `my_user` for it to work, but I have no idea how to debug it.

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: Note that your [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (the line that starts #!) has no effect, when it's not the first line of the file it's just another comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `su`**[YourUserName]**`-c /usr/bin/vncserver` to run the vncserver as user, not as root.

Another point: In your script, there's no difference between starting and stopping the VNC server. Usually, a init script would use different cases to start/stop the service:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
    # code to start the application
    ;;

    stop)
    # code to stop the application
    ;;

    restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
esac
```

[Here](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot)'s an elaborated example how to start a vnc server using an init script.

Comment: Thanks a lot tohuwawohu. This helped me to find errors in my script. I'll post it as another answer in about 8 hours, because my reputation doesn't allow me to do it just now (darn it).

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it. The problem was:

1. Running my script as root, which normally would happen, won't work. That's why it's necessary to use `su [my_user] -c`
2. One needs to use quotation marks for the options, ie.

   > su my_user -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16"
3. I also added `. /lib/lsb/init-functions` and `exit 0` - don't know if those are necessary, but for sure they don't do any harm. Just copied those from the elaborate example provided by *tohuwawohu*.

So I ended up with:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          startVNC
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: Start VNC server at boot time
# Description:       A sophisticated script to do the job.
### END INIT INFO

#!/bin/sh
echo "JOB RUN AT $(date)"
echo "============================"
echo ""

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
su my_user -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 16"

exit 0
```

Which works just fine. Of course, using the above cited [elaborate script](http://www.abdevelopment.ca/blog/start-vnc-server-ubuntu-boot) might be even better. I added the script to start-up via:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f startVNC start 99 2 3 4 5 .
```

because I don't see any reason to run anything on shutdown (beyond logging, which I'm not doing).

Also see the comment about the shebang (the line that starts #!) being misplaced here under my original question. It works, though, so I didn't want to include untested code here. You should change it probably if you'd like to use it.